# Bot Framework Error

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to run the [graph sentiment bot sample](https://github.com/richdizz/microsoft-graph-sentiment-bot) , on running in the emulator I am getting the below error

```
UniversalBot("*") routing "hi" from "emulator"
Session.beginDialog(/)
Error: Dialog[*:/] not found.
```

Comment: Bug has been reported on [source repository GitHub](https://github.com/richdizz/microsoft-graph-sentiment-bot/issues/2)

Comment: This is an error in the code example, not the Bot Framework SDK.